# Tools for web layout design

Tags: css, user-interface, web, wordpress-theming

I just started out trying to put a web site together for my own business. Web design is not my primary job so I basically wanted it to get it up running as fast as possible. I wanted some flexibility with the layout design so I avoided cookie cutter templates.

I started out choosing Wordpress Thesis theme. As the time goes on, I have most of the site content lined up. However, I am struggling to put all the pieces together to make the site design look uniform and professional. I tried CSS a little bit, spending a lot time on aligning web elements, font sizes, color coordination that sort of things and felt it would take me forever to finish the site.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a free tool suitable for beginner's skill level to reduce development time & compatible with Wordpress Thesis theme?

My line of business is selling products. So the site is pretty much like a product catalog with images, contents, news, & blogs.

I read a little on this site about CSS framework, also checked out jQuery-UI. just not sure if they are the right approach for what I want to accomplish.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebMatrix is a free and lightweight web development tool.
Create, publish, and maintain your website with ease. It is from Microsoft free tools.
you can download from Microsoft official website

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/), it does a WYSIWYG theme edition and can render Wordpress themes. 99$ but worth the money.